# Roman Letters in Japanese Postmarks

Tags: japan, postal-history

Why did the Japanese Post Office start using Roman characters in their postmarks for overseas mail in the late 1880s?

Comment: For **overseas** mail? I would guess so that people overseas can read them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 1877 [Japan joined](http://www.upu.int/en/the-upu/member-countries/southern-asia-and-oceania/japan.html) the [Universal Postal Union](http://news.upu.int/no_cache/nd/universal-postal-union-marks-140-years-as-part-of-berne-community/), which specifies cooperative rules for international mail.

The UPU’s history can be traced as far back as 1863, when then United States Postmaster General Montgomery Blair called a conference in Paris, France, to lay down a number of general principles for mutual agreements, but delegates failed to agree on an international postal agreement.

> Ten years later, Heinrich von Stephan, a senior postal official from
>   the North German Confederation, drew up a plan for an international
>   postal union, and upon his recommendation the Swiss Government
>   convened an international conference in Berne on 15 September 1874.
>   Representatives from 22 nations attended the conference, and on 9
>   October – a day now celebrated as World Post Day – the Treaty of Bern
>   establishing the General Postal Union was signed.
>
> This treaty succeeded in unifying a confusing international maze of
>   postal services and regulations into a single postal territory for the
>   reciprocal exchange of mail. The barriers and frontiers impeding the
>   free flow and growth of international mail had finally been pulled
>   down.
>
> Membership in the Union grew so quickly that its name was changed to
>   the Universal Postal Union in 1878. The organization became a United
>   Nations specialized agency for postal services in 1948.